# cannot load such file -- libxml_ruby for Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, libxml-ruby

My step is,

1. Execute RubyInstaller.exe file
2. install ruby
3. installed Path: c:\ruby193
4. install DevKit
5. gem install libxml-ruby --platform x86-mswin32-60
6. make test.rb file

   require 'rubygems'
    require 'xml'
7. ruby test.rb
8. print error msg

Error message:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
126: The specified module could not be found    - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/lib
xml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-60/lib/libxml_ruby.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-6    0/lib/libxml.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.3-x86-mswin32-6    0/lib/xml.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

i want solution in this problem
plz. help me.

Comment: Well, for some reason Ruby is looking for UNIX and Linux shared libraries, not Windows DLLs. I can't say why though.

Answer (score 7):

Had similar problem on Windows 7x64 with libxml-ruby 2.3.3 (Ruby 2, 1.9.3 and 1.9.2). As per this solution:

https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby/issues/42#issuecomment-7040881

I managed my problem was also solved. Solution (thanks to the original author):

1. Locate 'libxml.rb' in libxml-ruby gem folder (something like 'C:\Ruby\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\libxml-ruby-2.3.3-x86-mingw32\lib')
2. Add the following on top of the file:

   ENV['PATH'] = ENV['PATH'] + ';' + File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/libs')
3. Save and enjoy

Comment: What is "__FILE__"?? This doesn't work for me though... I still keep getting the same exception

Comment: @user3115056 did you find anything?